# Get Animation List current Image Index

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I am displaying an animation, and I would like to get the current Image Index value. I.e. if I have an animation list of 5 images, how can I get which image is displayingoing at the time each image is displayed. Can someone give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: Looking at the [**documentation**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) or [**source code**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.java/) there doesn't seem to any way to get the index of the current frame. There is a private field in the `AnimationDrawable` called `mCurFrame` which is the exact information you are looking for, but it is not exposed in any way.

Comment: My advice: If you really need it, implement your own version of the `AnimationDrawable`, otherwise just do the animation another way.

Comment: Also next time: Try to give us more information to go on. Show us your code, the exact xml or java code you use to create this animation. Otherwise any advice will just be guess work. For example I have no idea if you are really using an `AnimationDrawable`. I can just assume from your description that this is the most probable case.